# How to Run Angular8 dist folder without server

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to run angular8 dist folder in the browser directly without servers like wamp or HTTP server I want to run directly from index.html
if I try to run in chrome giving cors issue but it's working in EDGE

Comment: Why not just `ng serve`?

Comment: I need to give the dist folder as a project to another system(Multiple systems) that will not have ng. Previously we develop a project in angular js (1) their we gave the static files only I want in the same way

Comment: The contents of the dist folder don't need `ng` to be used, they just need to be safely downloadable. I assume the browser doesn't like using local files, but if you just upload them somewhere, I think it'd be fine. If you really NEED to open them locally, see if you can find a chrome extension that disables the cors problems.